# unknownhost exception from java while connecting to mariadb after some idle wildfly time

Tags: java

I have deployed my application war on wildfly in linux i am connecting to maraidb. initially the connections works fine application is also working finr but after around 30 minutes i am getting below error giving unknownhostexception.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not cre    ate connection to d    atabase server.     attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:108)
>           at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:71)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:932)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.cre    ateNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:857)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverD    ataSource.getConnection(DriverD    ataSource.java:117)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverD    ataSource.getConnection(DriverD    ataSource.java:123)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.cre    atePoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCre    ator.call(HikariPool.java:699)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCre    ator.call(HikariPool.java:685)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       ... 3 more
>       Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunic    ationsException: Communic    ations link failure
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not cre    ate connection to d    atabase server.     attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:108)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.cre    ateSQLException(SQLError.java:71)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:932)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.cre    ateNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:857)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverD    ataSource.getConnection(DriverD    ataSource.java:117)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverD    ataSource.getConnection(DriverD    ataSource.java:123)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.cre    atePoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCre    ator.call(HikariPool.java:699)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCre    ator.call(HikariPool.java:685)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       ... 3 more
>       Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunic    ationsException: Communic    ations link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>       at sun.reflect.Gener    atedConstructorAccessor56.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.Deleg    atingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Deleg    atingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.cre    ateException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.cre    ateException(ExceptionFactory.java:103)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.cre    ateException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.cre    ateCommunic    ationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:165)
>       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.N    ativeSocketConnection.connect(N    ativeSocketConnection.java:92)
>       at com.mysql.cj.N    ativeSession.connect(N    ativeSession.java:152)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:876)
>       ... 16 more
>       Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: frbrtx06linx205
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
>       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:150)
>       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.N    ativeSocketConnection.connect(N    ativeSocketConnection.java:66)
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>       at sun.reflect.Gener    atedConstructorAccessor56.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.Deleg    atingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Deleg    atingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.cre    ateException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.cre    ateException(ExceptionFactory.java:103)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.cre    ateException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.cre    ateCommunic    ationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:165)
>       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.N    ativeSocketConnection.connect(N    ativeSocketConnection.java:92)
>       at com.mysql.cj.N    ativeSession.connect(N    ativeSession.java:152)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:876)
>       ... 16 more
>       Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: frbrtx06linx205
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
>       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:150)
>   'at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.N    ativeSocketConnection.connect(N   'ativeSocketConnection.java:66)`

i have some 100+ such services and this code is using spring boot  i am using hikaridatasource  but in each service i am opening and closing entitymanager that should close the connection

```
package com.att.cerebro.Agiletool.repositories;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.att.cerebro.Agiletool.entitybeans.Attachment;

@Component
public class AttachmentRepositoryImpl implements AttachmentRepository {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Transactional
    public String addAttachment(Attachment attachment) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory
                .createEntityManager();

        try {
            StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager
                    .createStoredProcedureQuery("agile_addAttachment");

            // Set the parameters of the stored procedure.

            String TypeId = attachment.getTypeId();

            String FileName = attachment.getFileName();
            String Filedesc = attachment.getFileDesc();

            String Filetype = attachment.getFileType();
            byte[] FileData = attachment.getFileData();

            int AppId = attachment.getAppId();

            String CreatedBy = attachment.getCreatedBy();

            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("TypeId",
                    String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("FileName",
                    String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Filedesc",
                    String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Filetype",
                    String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("FileData",
                    byte[].class, ParameterMode.IN);

            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("CreatedBy",
                    String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("AppId",
                    Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

            storedProcedure.setParameter("TypeId", TypeId);

            storedProcedure.setParameter("FileName", FileName);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("Filedesc", Filedesc);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("Filetype", Filetype);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("FileData", FileData);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("AppId", AppId);

            storedProcedure.setParameter("CreatedBy", CreatedBy);

            storedProcedure.execute();

            List<BigInteger> storedProcedureResults = storedProcedure
                    .getResultList();

            return storedProcedureResults.get(0).toString();
        } finally {
            if (entityManager != null) {
                entityManager.close();
            }

        }

    }

}
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .html
server.port:8082

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://frbrtx06linx205:3306/CerebroUT?autoReconnect=true
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CerebroDev?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root

#spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE 
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true


spring.datasource.dbcp.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dbcp.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=3600000
spring.datasource.dbcp.validation-query=SELECT 1


#spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=1
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=200
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=DevEnvPool
spring.jmx.default-domain=CerebroDev
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000



spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true


warp.csp.url=https://www.e-access.att.com/empsvcs/hrpinmgt/pagLogin/?retURL=
warp.csp.cookiename=attESSec
warp.csp.gatekeeperenv=DEVL
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Can you still ping the database's host from your wildfly's host once this happens?

Comment: This looks a lot like a network failure, in particular because your JVM tells you it can't resolve `frbrtx06linx205`

Comment: my database and code are on same host  and this error goes away after wildfly restart . will share the code

Comment: I'm not sure we will be able to see much in the code, the error concerns database connection establishment which doesn't depend on your app's code. The datasource's definition might help though. Is `frbrtx06linx205` indeed the hostname of your machine? How is it defined on your machine, through the /etc/hosts, or by a DNS server? Could you try the ping after the error happens? If your database will always be on the same machine as the wildfly, it might solve the problem to just use `localhost` instead of `frbrtx06linx205` in the datasource definition.

Comment: yes frbrtx06linx205 is hostname .. my hosts file has localhost for loopback address 127.0.0.1 .. as wildfly and mariadb both are on same host.. since hosts file doesnt have this hostname i guess it might be for DNS server

Comment: The DNS failing to resolve is worrisome but I doubt I'll be able to help you there. If you've got a sysadmin/network admin you should ask his help identifying the problem, otherwise you could try to replicate it on the OS level and ask for guidance on https://serverfault.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/. In the meantime I think you should fix your datasource definition so it does not rely on the `frbrtx06linx205` hostname, unnecessarily using an hostname your machine might not be able to resolve is a risk anyway. Either use localhost, define the host it in your /etc/hosts, or use the IP

Comment: ok thnx alot Aaron let me try with localhost or ip

Comment: it worked with localhost.. thnx Aaron DNS seems to be the issue probably..